# How to create an anonymous object while inserting into a dictionary using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary ftpList that would contain value of an object. At the moment, I have it as

```
JSONElementList tt = new JSONElementList();
ftpList.Add(key,tt);
```

Is there a way to do it such that I would use linq as follows:

```
ftpList.add(key, () => new JSONElementList());
```

?

When I tried it gives an error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'com .. etc etc' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: `ftpList.add(key, new JSONElementList());`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ftpList.add(key, new JSONElementList());
```

Now you are trying to use a lamdba expression as the `Value`, not the newly created object.

The signature of the dictionary you were trying to insert to is:

```
Dictionary<object, Action>
```

Comment: @SamIAm: need more help?